# port to subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, port-forwarding, hudson

I have installed Hudson using apt-get, and the Hudson server is available on `example.com:8080`.

For `example.com` I use standard port *:80 and some virtual hosts set up this way:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/subdomain.example.com
<Virtualhost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
  ...
</Virtualhost>
```

Here is info about Hudson process:

```
/usr/bin/daemon --name=hudson --inherit --env=HUDSON_HOME=/var/lib/hudson --output=/var/log/hudson/hudson.log --pidfile=/var/run/hudson/hudson.pid -- /usr/bin/java -jar /usr/share/hudson/hudson.war --webroot=/var/run/hudson/war
  987 ?        Sl     1:08 /usr/bin/java -jar /usr/share/hudson/hudson.war --webroot=/var/run/hudson/war
```

How should I forward:

```
    http:// example.com:8080
```

to:

```
    http:// hudson.example.com
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to enable mod_proxy in Apache2 first. So run these commands as root, or sudo:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

You'll then need to restart apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Your HUDSON vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName hudson.example.com
ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/hudson
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/hudson
ProxyRequests     Off

# Local reverse proxy authorization override
# Most unix distribution deny proxy by default 
# (ie /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf in Ubuntu)
<Proxy http://localhost:8080/hudson*>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache one more time to commit the new vhost:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

- Hudson Documention on running it behind Apache: [LINK](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Running+Hudson+behind+Apache)
- Apache2.2 doc on running ProxyPass subdomains: [LINK](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works (I only had to change :8080/hudson to :8080), but now the stylesheets are not loading. When I try to access them directly I get: `The proxy server could not handle the request GET /static/10302538/css/style.css. 
Reason: DNS lookup failure for: localhost:8080static`

Comment: make sure **127.0.0.1 localhost** is in your /etc/hosts file.

Comment: It is: 127.0.0.1 localhost 192.168.1.2 example.com

Comment: Found a possible answer. Put a trailing slash after the :8080. You removed it when you deleted the word "hudson" from the vhost config file. So it would look like:: **http://localhost:8080/** on applicable lines. Restart apache and let me know how that works out.